# error installing mvc 4

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

Please excuse the length of this post, I wanted to include all info i deemed necessary to debug.

I've been unable to install mvc 4 for vs 2010 after many attempts. I had the mvc 4 beta installed because I created a webapi project. I also had mvc 2 & 3 installed. I uninstalled mvc 4 using the (bundle) link in Programs n Features ... Now trying to install mvc 4 and i'm getting an  undescriptive error log that  I can't make heads or tails of ... any help would be appreciated.

My system environment contains

windows 7 x64 enterprise
vs 2010 sp1 ( see info below log file)
Web Platform Installer 4.0

```
[201C:04BC][2012-06-12T11:09:18]: Burn v3.6.2712.0, path: C:\Users\<userName>\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Web Platform Installer\installers\MVC4VS2010\8EDB940F9A4EEC0C0F0324B5D647F17738C665CA\AspNetMVC4Setup.exe, cmdline: '/q /log C:\Users\<userName>\AppData\Local\Temp\MVC4_install.htm -burn.unelevated BurnPipe.{B9B09A3A-ED62-4F21-931F-941AE3AD242A} {FC1D5F36-4FCF-44CC-A4A5-B430AEC97063} 7584'
[201C:04BC][2012-06-12T11:09:18]: Setting string variable 'WixBundleLog' to value 'C:\Users\<userName>\AppData\Local\Temp\MVC4_install.htm'
[201C:04BC][2012-06-12T11:09:18]: Setting string variable 'WixBundleOriginalSource' to value 'C:\Users\<userName>\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Web Platform Installer\installers\MVC4VS2010\8EDB940F9A4EEC0C0F0324B5D647F17738C665CA\AspNetMVC4Setup.exe'
[201C:04BC][2012-06-12T11:09:18]: Setting string variable 'WixBundleName' to value 'Microsoft ASP.NET MVC 4'
[201C:04BC][2012-06-12T11:09:18]: Detect 9 packages
[201C:04BC][2012-06-12T11:09:18]: Setting string variable 'netfx4' to value '4.0.30319'
[201C:04BC][2012-06-12T11:09:18]: Setting version variable 'PowerShellExeVersion' to value '6.1.7600.16385'
[201C:04BC][2012-06-12T11:09:18]: Setting numeric variable 'procore2010_exists' to value 1
[201C:04BC][2012-06-12T11:09:18]: Setting string variable 'procore2010_sp1' to value '40219.342'
[201C:04BC][2012-06-12T11:09:18]: Registry key not found. Key = 'Software\Microsoft\DevDiv\VS\Servicing\10.0\vstdcore'
[201C:04BC][2012-06-12T11:09:18]: Setting numeric variable 'vstdcore2010_exists' to value 0
[201C:04BC][2012-06-12T11:09:18]: Registry key not found. Key = 'Software\Microsoft\DevDiv\VS\Servicing\10.0\vstdcore'
[201C:04BC][2012-06-12T11:09:18]: Registry key not found. Key = 'Software\Microsoft\DevDiv\VS\Servicing\10.0\vstscore'
[201C:04BC][2012-06-12T11:09:18]: Setting numeric variable 'vstscore2010_exists' to value 0
[201C:04BC][2012-06-12T11:09:18]: Registry key not found. Key = 'Software\Microsoft\DevDiv\VS\Servicing\10.0\vstscore'
[201C:04BC][2012-06-12T11:09:18]: Registry key not found. Key = 'Software\Microsoft\DevDiv\vns\Servicing\10.0\xcor'
[201C:04BC][2012-06-12T11:09:18]: Setting numeric variable 'xcor2010_exists' to value 0
[201C:04BC][2012-06-12T11:09:18]: Registry key not found. Key = 'Software\Microsoft\DevDiv\vns\Servicing\10.0\xcor'
[201C:04BC][2012-06-12T11:09:18]: Detected package: VS10SP1_KB2581019_x86.exe, state: Absent, cached: Complete
[201C:04BC][2012-06-12T11:09:18]: Detected package: VS10SP1_KB2591016_x86.exe, state: Absent, cached: Complete
[201C:04BC][2012-06-12T11:09:18]: Detected package: Nuget.msi, state: Absent, cached: Complete
[201C:04BC][2012-06-12T11:09:18]: Detected package: AspNetWebPages2.msi, state: Present, cached: Complete
[201C:04BC][2012-06-12T11:09:18]: Detected package: AspNetWebPages2VS2010Tools.msi, state: Absent, cached: Complete
[201C:04BC][2012-06-12T11:09:18]: Detected package: AspNetWebPages2VWD2010Tools.msi, state: Absent, cached: None
[201C:04BC][2012-06-12T11:09:18]: Detected package: AspNetMVC4.msi, state: Absent, cached: Complete
[201C:04BC][2012-06-12T11:09:18]: Detected package: AspNetMVC4VS2010Tools.msi, state: Absent, cached: Complete
[201C:04BC][2012-06-12T11:09:18]: Detected package: AspNetMVC4VWD2010Tools.msi, state: Absent, cached: None
[201C:04BC][2012-06-12T11:09:18]: Condition '((NOT vstscore2010_exists) OR ((vstscore2010_sp1 >= v40219.01) AND (vstscore2010_exists))) AND ((NOT vstdcore2010_exists) OR ((vstdcore2010_sp1 >= v40219.01) AND (vstdcore2010_exists))) AND ((NOT procore2010_exists) OR ((procore2010_sp1 >= v40219.01) AND (procore2010_exists)))' evaluates to true.
[201C:04BC][2012-06-12T11:09:18]: Condition '(NOT xcor2010_exists) OR ((xcor2010_sp1 >= v40219.01) AND (xcor2010_exists))' evaluates to true.
[201C:04BC][2012-06-12T11:09:18]: Condition 'netfx4 >= v4.0.30319' evaluates to true.
[201C:04BC][2012-06-12T11:09:18]: Condition 'NOT (netfx4 > v4.0.30319 AND netfx4 < v4.5.50131)' evaluates to true.
[201C:04BC][2012-06-12T11:09:18]: Condition 'PowerShellExeVersion >= v2.0' evaluates to true.
[201C:04BC][2012-06-12T11:09:18]: Detect complete, result: 0x0
[201C:04BC][2012-06-12T11:09:18]: Plan 9 packages, action: Install
[201C:04BC][2012-06-12T11:09:18]: Condition '((vstscore2010_sp1 >= v40219.01) AND (vstscore2010_exists)) OR ((vstdcore2010_sp1 >= v40219.01) AND (vstdcore2010_exists)) OR ((procore2010_sp1 >= v40219.01) AND (procore2010_exists)) OR ((xcor2010_sp1 >= v40219.01) AND (xcor2010_exists))' evaluates to true.
[201C:04BC][2012-06-12T11:09:18]: Skipping dependency registration on package with no dependency providers: VS10SP1_KB2581019_x86.exe
[201C:04BC][2012-06-12T11:09:18]: Setting string variable 'WixBundleLog_VS10SP1_KB2581019_x86.exe' to value 'C:\Users\<userName>\AppData\Local\Temp\MVC4_install_0_VS10SP1_KB2581019_x86.exe.htm'
[201C:04BC][2012-06-12T11:09:18]: Condition '((vstscore2010_sp1 >= v40219.01) AND (vstscore2010_exists)) OR ((vstdcore2010_sp1 >= v40219.01) AND (vstdcore2010_exists)) OR ((procore2010_sp1 >= v40219.01) AND (procore2010_exists)) OR ((xcor2010_sp1 >= v40219.01) AND (xcor2010_exists))' evaluates to true.
[201C:04BC][2012-06-12T11:09:18]: Skipping dependency registration on package with no dependency providers: VS10SP1_KB2591016_x86.exe
[201C:04BC][2012-06-12T11:09:18]: Setting string variable 'WixBundleLog_VS10SP1_KB2591016_x86.exe' to value 'C:\Users\<userName>\AppData\Local\Temp\MVC4_install_1_VS10SP1_KB2591016_x86.exe.htm'
[201C:04BC][2012-06-12T11:09:18]: Condition '((vstscore2010_sp1 >= v40219.01) AND (vstscore2010_exists)) OR ((vstdcore2010_sp1 >= v40219.01) AND (vstdcore2010_exists)) OR ((procore2010_sp1 >= v40219.01) AND (procore2010_exists)) OR ((xcor2010_sp1 >= v40219.01) AND (xcor2010_exists))' evaluates to true.
[201C:04BC][2012-06-12T11:09:18]: Setting string variable 'WixBundleRollbackLog_Nuget.msi' to value 'C:\Users\<userName>\AppData\Local\Temp\MVC4_install_2_Nuget.msi_rollback.htm'
[201C:04BC][2012-06-12T11:09:18]: Setting string variable 'WixBundleLog_Nuget.msi' to value 'C:\Users\<userName>\AppData\Local\Temp\MVC4_install_2_Nuget.msi.htm'
[201C:04BC][2012-06-12T11:09:18]: Condition '((vstscore2010_sp1 >= v40219.01) AND (vstscore2010_exists)) OR ((vstdcore2010_sp1 >= v40219.01) AND (vstdcore2010_exists)) OR ((procore2010_sp1 >= v40219.01) AND (procore2010_exists))' evaluates to true.
[201C:04BC][2012-06-12T11:09:18]: Setting string variable 'WixBundleRollbackLog_AspNetWebPages2VS2010Tools.msi' to value 'C:\Users\<userName>\AppData\Local\Temp\MVC4_install_3_AspNetWebPages2VS2010Tools.msi_rollback.htm'
[201C:04BC][2012-06-12T11:09:18]: Setting string variable 'WixBundleLog_AspNetWebPages2VS2010Tools.msi' to value 'C:\Users\<userName>\AppData\Local\Temp\MVC4_install_3_AspNetWebPages2VS2010Tools.msi.htm'
[201C:04BC][2012-06-12T11:09:18]: Condition '(xcor2010_sp1 >= v40219.01) AND (xcor2010_exists)' evaluates to false.
[201C:04BC][2012-06-12T11:09:18]: Setting string variable 'WixBundleRollbackLog_AspNetMVC4.msi' to value 'C:\Users\<userName>\AppData\Local\Temp\MVC4_install_4_AspNetMVC4.msi_rollback.htm'
[201C:04BC][2012-06-12T11:09:18]: Setting string variable 'WixBundleLog_AspNetMVC4.msi' to value 'C:\Users\<userName>\AppData\Local\Temp\MVC4_install_4_AspNetMVC4.msi.htm'
[201C:04BC][2012-06-12T11:09:18]: Condition '((vstscore2010_sp1 >= v40219.01) AND (vstscore2010_exists)) OR ((vstdcore2010_sp1 >= v40219.01) AND (vstdcore2010_exists)) OR ((procore2010_sp1 >= v40219.01) AND (procore2010_exists))' evaluates to true.
[201C:04BC][2012-06-12T11:09:18]: Setting string variable 'WixBundleRollbackLog_AspNetMVC4VS2010Tools.msi' to value 'C:\Users\<userName>\AppData\Local\Temp\MVC4_install_5_AspNetMVC4VS2010Tools.msi_rollback.htm'
[201C:04BC][2012-06-12T11:09:18]: Setting string variable 'WixBundleLog_AspNetMVC4VS2010Tools.msi' to value 'C:\Users\<userName>\AppData\Local\Temp\MVC4_install_5_AspNetMVC4VS2010Tools.msi.htm'
[201C:04BC][2012-06-12T11:09:18]: Condition '(xcor2010_sp1 >= v40219.01) AND (xcor2010_exists)' evaluates to false.
[201C:04BC][2012-06-12T11:09:18]: Planned package: VS10SP1_KB2581019_x86.exe, state: Absent, default requested: Present, ba requested: Present, execute: Install, rollback: None, cache: No, uncache: No, dependency: None
[201C:04BC][2012-06-12T11:09:18]: Planned package: VS10SP1_KB2591016_x86.exe, state: Absent, default requested: Present, ba requested: Present, execute: Install, rollback: None, cache: No, uncache: No, dependency: None
[201C:04BC][2012-06-12T11:09:18]: Planned package: Nuget.msi, state: Absent, default requested: Present, ba requested: Present, execute: Install, rollback: Uninstall, cache: No, uncache: No, dependency: Register
[201C:04BC][2012-06-12T11:09:18]: Planned package: AspNetWebPages2.msi, state: Present, default requested: Present, ba requested: Present, execute: None, rollback: None, cache: No, uncache: No, dependency: Register
[201C:04BC][2012-06-12T11:09:18]: Planned package: AspNetWebPages2VS2010Tools.msi, state: Absent, default requested: Present, ba requested: Present, execute: Install, rollback: Uninstall, cache: No, uncache: No, dependency: Register
[201C:04BC][2012-06-12T11:09:18]: Planned package: AspNetWebPages2VWD2010Tools.msi, state: Absent, default requested: Absent, ba requested: Absent, execute: None, rollback: None, cache: No, uncache: No, dependency: None
[201C:04BC][2012-06-12T11:09:18]: Planned package: AspNetMVC4.msi, state: Absent, default requested: Present, ba requested: Present, execute: Install, rollback: Uninstall, cache: No, uncache: No, dependency: Register
[201C:04BC][2012-06-12T11:09:18]: Planned package: AspNetMVC4VS2010Tools.msi, state: Absent, default requested: Present, ba requested: Present, execute: Install, rollback: Uninstall, cache: No, uncache: No, dependency: Register
[201C:04BC][2012-06-12T11:09:18]: Planned package: AspNetMVC4VWD2010Tools.msi, state: Absent, default requested: Absent, ba requested: Absent, execute: None, rollback: None, cache: No, uncache: No, dependency: None
[201C:04BC][2012-06-12T11:09:18]: Plan complete, result: 0x0
[201C:04BC][2012-06-12T11:09:18]: Apply begin
[1DA0:2234][2012-06-12T11:09:18]: Automatic updates could not be paused due to error: 0x80240025. Continuing...
[1DA0:2234][2012-06-12T11:09:18]: Creating a system restore point.
[1DA0:2234][2012-06-12T11:09:18]: Could not create system restore point, error: 0x80070422. Continuing...
[1DA0:2234][2012-06-12T11:09:18]: Caching bundle from: 'C:\Users\<userName>\AppData\Local\Temp\{a2aa0550-73d2-4f8e-ade9-b901851851fc}\.be\AspNetMVC4Setup.exe' to: 'C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\{a2aa0550-73d2-4f8e-ade9-b901851851fc}\AspNetMVC4Setup.exe'
[1DA0:2234][2012-06-12T11:09:19]: Registering bundle dependency provider: {a2aa0550-73d2-4f8e-ade9-b901851851fc}, version: 4.0.20505.0
[1DA0:02BC][2012-06-12T11:09:19]: Verified existing payload: VS10SP1_KB2581019_x86.exe at path: C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\9ACF484DD18F53B5E56809ABA965A32DACE6A809\VS10SP1-KB2581019-x86.exe.
[1DA0:02BC][2012-06-12T11:09:19]: Verified existing payload: VS10SP1_KB2591016_x86.exe at path: C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\5BA5217D49F8BECD7CA452F2F366CD7C99FF1F16\VS10SP1-KB2591016-x86.exe.
[1DA0:02BC][2012-06-12T11:09:19]: Verified existing payload: Nuget.msi at path: C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\{8FEC8DF9-6B13-4CAD-8FF3-063F332D16EB}v1.8.20505.0\Nuget.msi.
[1DA0:02BC][2012-06-12T11:09:19]: Verified existing payload: AspNetWebPages2VS2010Tools.msi at path: C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\{01866492-9599-46F4-BE9A-F6A264C09108}v2.0.20505.0\AspNetWebPages2VS2010Tools.msi.
[1DA0:02BC][2012-06-12T11:09:19]: Verified existing payload: cab3ECB64089A75B346241FCE810109AA85 at path: C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\{01866492-9599-46F4-BE9A-F6A264C09108}v2.0.20505.0\WebPages2_VisualStudio2010.cab.
[1DA0:02BC][2012-06-12T11:09:19]: Verified existing payload: AspNetMVC4.msi at path: C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\{8719C066-3A8C-4528-B82F-5094DB869F43}v4.0.20505.0\AspNetMVC4.msi.
[1DA0:02BC][2012-06-12T11:09:19]: Verified existing payload: cab4B3E83F27633398CE0AAFFFED6B2BF23 at path: C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\{8719C066-3A8C-4528-B82F-5094DB869F43}v4.0.20505.0\MVC4_runtime.cab.
[1DA0:02BC][2012-06-12T11:09:19]: Verified existing payload: AspNetMVC4VS2010Tools.msi at path: C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\{EA14A6CE-A0E1-410D-872D-B04CC186BA99}v4.0.20505.0\AspNetMVC4VS2010Tools.msi.
[1DA0:02BC][2012-06-12T11:09:19]: Verified existing payload: cabB4603D3274E047299B381454BE3590A6 at path: C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\{EA14A6CE-A0E1-410D-872D-B04CC186BA99}v4.0.20505.0\MVC4_VisualStudio2010.cab.
[1DA0:2234][2012-06-12T11:09:19]: Applying execute package: VS10SP1_KB2581019_x86.exe, action: Install, path: C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\9ACF484DD18F53B5E56809ABA965A32DACE6A809\VS10SP1-KB2581019-x86.exe, arguments: '"C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\9ACF484DD18F53B5E56809ABA965A32DACE6A809\VS10SP1-KB2581019-x86.exe" /q /norestart'
[1DA0:2234][2012-06-12T11:09:21]: Error 0x8007066a: Process returned error: 0x66a
[1DA0:2234][2012-06-12T11:09:21]: Error 0x8007066a: Failed to execute EXE package.
[201C:04BC][2012-06-12T11:09:21]: Error 0x8007066a: Failed to configure per-machine EXE package.
[201C:04BC][2012-06-12T11:09:21]: Error 0x8007066a: Failed to execute EXE package.
[1DA0:2234][2012-06-12T11:09:21]: Removing bundle dependency provider: {a2aa0550-73d2-4f8e-ade9-b901851851fc}
[1DA0:2234][2012-06-12T11:09:21]: Removing cached bundle: {a2aa0550-73d2-4f8e-ade9-b901851851fc}, from path: C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\{a2aa0550-73d2-4f8e-ade9-b901851851fc}\
[201C:04BC][2012-06-12T11:09:21]: Apply complete, result: 0x8007066a restart: No
[201C:04BC][2012-06-12T11:09:21]: Shutting down, exit code: 0x8007066a
[201C:04BC][2012-06-12T11:09:21]: Variable: AdminToolsFolder = C:\Users\<userName>\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Administrative Tools\
[201C:04BC][2012-06-12T11:09:21]: Variable: AppDataFolder = C:\Users\<userName>\AppData\Roaming\
[201C:04BC][2012-06-12T11:09:21]: Variable: CommonAppDataFolder = C:\ProgramData\
[201C:04BC][2012-06-12T11:09:21]: Variable: CommonFiles64Folder = C:\Program Files\Common Files
[201C:04BC][2012-06-12T11:09:21]: Variable: CommonFilesFolder = C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\
[201C:04BC][2012-06-12T11:09:21]: Variable: CompatibilityMode = 1
[201C:04BC][2012-06-12T11:09:21]: Variable: Date = 6/12/2012
[201C:04BC][2012-06-12T11:09:21]: Variable: DesktopFolder = C:\Users\<userName>\Desktop\
[201C:04BC][2012-06-12T11:09:21]: Variable: FavoritesFolder = C:\Users\<userName>\Favorites\
[201C:04BC][2012-06-12T11:09:21]: Variable: FontsFolder = C:\Windows\Fonts\
[201C:04BC][2012-06-12T11:09:21]: Variable: InstallerName = WiX Burn
[201C:04BC][2012-06-12T11:09:21]: Variable: InstallerVersion = 3.6.2712.0
[201C:04BC][2012-06-12T11:09:21]: Variable: LocalAppDataFolder = C:\Users\<userName>\AppData\Local\
[201C:04BC][2012-06-12T11:09:21]: Variable: LogonUser = <userName>
[201C:04BC][2012-06-12T11:09:21]: Variable: MyPicturesFolder = C:\Users\<userName>\Pictures\
[201C:04BC][2012-06-12T11:09:21]: Variable: netfx4 = 4.0.30319
[201C:04BC][2012-06-12T11:09:21]: Variable: NTProductType = 1
[201C:04BC][2012-06-12T11:09:21]: Variable: NTSuiteBackOffice = 0
[201C:04BC][2012-06-12T11:09:21]: Variable: NTSuiteDataCenter = 0
[201C:04BC][2012-06-12T11:09:21]: Variable: NTSuiteEnterprise = 0
[201C:04BC][2012-06-12T11:09:21]: Variable: NTSuitePersonal = 0
[201C:04BC][2012-06-12T11:09:21]: Variable: NTSuiteSmallBusiness = 0
[201C:04BC][2012-06-12T11:09:21]: Variable: NTSuiteSmallBusinessRestricted = 0
[201C:04BC][2012-06-12T11:09:21]: Variable: NTSuiteWebServer = 0
[201C:04BC][2012-06-12T11:09:21]: Variable: PersonalFolder = C:\Users\<userName>\Documents\
[201C:04BC][2012-06-12T11:09:21]: Variable: PowerShellExeVersion = 6.1.7600.16385
[201C:04BC][2012-06-12T11:09:21]: Variable: Privileged = 1
[201C:04BC][2012-06-12T11:09:21]: Variable: procore2010_exists = 1
[201C:04BC][2012-06-12T11:09:21]: Variable: procore2010_sp1 = 40219.342
[201C:04BC][2012-06-12T11:09:21]: Variable: ProgramFiles64Folder = C:\Program Files
[201C:04BC][2012-06-12T11:09:21]: Variable: ProgramFilesFolder = C:\Program Files (x86)\
[201C:04BC][2012-06-12T11:09:21]: Variable: ProgramMenuFolder = C:\Users\<userName>\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\
[201C:04BC][2012-06-12T11:09:21]: Variable: RebootPending = 0
[201C:04BC][2012-06-12T11:09:21]: Variable: SendToFolder = C:\Users\<userName>\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\SendTo\
[201C:04BC][2012-06-12T11:09:21]: Variable: ServicePackLevel = 1
[201C:04BC][2012-06-12T11:09:21]: Variable: StartMenuFolder = C:\Users\<userName>\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\
[201C:04BC][2012-06-12T11:09:21]: Variable: StartupFolder = C:\Users\<userName>\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup\
[201C:04BC][2012-06-12T11:09:21]: Variable: System64Folder = C:\Windows\SysWOW64\
[201C:04BC][2012-06-12T11:09:21]: Variable: SystemFolder = C:\Windows\system32\
[201C:04BC][2012-06-12T11:09:21]: Variable: SystemLanguageID = 1033
[201C:04BC][2012-06-12T11:09:21]: Variable: TempFolder = C:\Users\<userName>\AppData\Local\Temp\
[201C:04BC][2012-06-12T11:09:21]: Variable: TemplateFolder = C:\Users\<userName>\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Templates\
[201C:04BC][2012-06-12T11:09:21]: Variable: TerminalServer = 0
[201C:04BC][2012-06-12T11:09:21]: Variable: UserLanguageID = 1033
[201C:04BC][2012-06-12T11:09:21]: Variable: VersionMsi = 5.0.0.0
[201C:04BC][2012-06-12T11:09:21]: Variable: VersionNT = 6.1.0.0
[201C:04BC][2012-06-12T11:09:21]: Variable: VersionNT64 = 6.1.0.0
[201C:04BC][2012-06-12T11:09:21]: Variable: vstdcore2010_exists = 0
[201C:04BC][2012-06-12T11:09:21]: Variable: vstdcore2010_sp1 = 
[201C:04BC][2012-06-12T11:09:21]: Variable: vstscore2010_exists = 0
[201C:04BC][2012-06-12T11:09:21]: Variable: vstscore2010_sp1 = 
[201C:04BC][2012-06-12T11:09:21]: Variable: WindowsFolder = C:\Windows\
[201C:04BC][2012-06-12T11:09:21]: Variable: WindowsVolume = C:\
[201C:04BC][2012-06-12T11:09:21]: Variable: WixBundleAction = 4
[201C:04BC][2012-06-12T11:09:21]: Variable: WixBundleElevated = 1
[201C:04BC][2012-06-12T11:09:21]: Variable: WixBundleInstalled = 0
[201C:04BC][2012-06-12T11:09:21]: Variable: WixBundleLastUsedSource = 
[201C:04BC][2012-06-12T11:09:21]: Variable: WixBundleLog = C:\Users\<userName>\AppData\Local\Temp\MVC4_install.htm
[201C:04BC][2012-06-12T11:09:21]: Variable: WixBundleLog_AspNetMVC4.msi = C:\Users\<userName>\AppData\Local\Temp\MVC4_install_4_AspNetMVC4.msi.htm
[201C:04BC][2012-06-12T11:09:21]: Variable: WixBundleLog_AspNetMVC4VS2010Tools.msi = C:\Users\<userName>\AppData\Local\Temp\MVC4_install_5_AspNetMVC4VS2010Tools.msi.htm
[201C:04BC][2012-06-12T11:09:21]: Variable: WixBundleLog_AspNetWebPages2VS2010Tools.msi = C:\Users\<userName>\AppData\Local\Temp\MVC4_install_3_AspNetWebPages2VS2010Tools.msi.htm
[201C:04BC][2012-06-12T11:09:21]: Variable: WixBundleLog_Nuget.msi = C:\Users\<userName>\AppData\Local\Temp\MVC4_install_2_Nuget.msi.htm
[201C:04BC][2012-06-12T11:09:21]: Variable: WixBundleLog_VS10SP1_KB2581019_x86.exe = C:\Users\<userName>\AppData\Local\Temp\MVC4_install_0_VS10SP1_KB2581019_x86.exe.htm
[201C:04BC][2012-06-12T11:09:21]: Variable: WixBundleLog_VS10SP1_KB2591016_x86.exe = C:\Users\<userName>\AppData\Local\Temp\MVC4_install_1_VS10SP1_KB2591016_x86.exe.htm
[201C:04BC][2012-06-12T11:09:21]: Variable: WixBundleName = Microsoft ASP.NET MVC 4
[201C:04BC][2012-06-12T11:09:21]: Variable: WixBundleOriginalSource = C:\Users\<userName>\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Web Platform Installer\installers\MVC4VS2010\8EDB940F9A4EEC0C0F0324B5D647F17738C665CA\AspNetMVC4Setup.exe
[201C:04BC][2012-06-12T11:09:21]: Variable: WixBundleProviderKey = {a2aa0550-73d2-4f8e-ade9-b901851851fc}
[201C:04BC][2012-06-12T11:09:21]: Variable: WixBundleRollbackLog_AspNetMVC4.msi = C:\Users\<userName>\AppData\Local\Temp\MVC4_install_4_AspNetMVC4.msi_rollback.htm
[201C:04BC][2012-06-12T11:09:21]: Variable: WixBundleRollbackLog_AspNetMVC4VS2010Tools.msi = C:\Users\<userName>\AppData\Local\Temp\MVC4_install_5_AspNetMVC4VS2010Tools.msi_rollback.htm
[201C:04BC][2012-06-12T11:09:21]: Variable: WixBundleRollbackLog_AspNetWebPages2VS2010Tools.msi = C:\Users\<userName>\AppData\Local\Temp\MVC4_install_3_AspNetWebPages2VS2010Tools.msi_rollback.htm
[201C:04BC][2012-06-12T11:09:21]: Variable: WixBundleRollbackLog_Nuget.msi = C:\Users\<userName>\AppData\Local\Temp\MVC4_install_2_Nuget.msi_rollback.htm
[201C:04BC][2012-06-12T11:09:21]: Variable: WixBundleTag = 
[201C:04BC][2012-06-12T11:09:21]: Variable: xcor2010_exists = 0
[201C:04BC][2012-06-12T11:09:21]: Variable: xcor2010_sp1 = 
[201C:04BC][2012-06-12T11:09:21]: Exit code: 0x8007066a


----------------------------log file from  wpi 4.0 installer---------------------------

DownloadManager Information: 0 : Loading product xml from: https://go.microsoft.com/?linkid=9808264
DownloadManager Information: 0 : https://go.microsoft.com/?linkid=9808264 responded with 302
DownloadManager Information: 0 : Response headers:
HTTP/1.1 302 Found
Cache-Control: private
Content-Length: 175
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Expires: Tue, 12 Jun 2012 15:08:06 GMT
Location: https://www.microsoft.com/web/webpi/4.0/webproductlist.xml
Server: Microsoft-IIS/7.5
X-AspNet-Version: 2.0.50727
Set-Cookie: MC1=GUID=7bc9a4edd0644146a30aa6f87cb93196&HASH=eda4&LV=20126&V=3; domain=microsoft.com; expires=Sun, 03-Oct-2010 07:00:00 GMT; path=/
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
Date: Tue, 12 Jun 2012 15:09:06 GMT


DownloadManager Information: 0 : https://www.microsoft.com/web/webpi/4.0/webproductlist.xml responded with 304
DownloadManager Information: 0 : Response headers:
HTTP/1.1 304 Not Modified
Cache-Control: max-age=900
Accept-Ranges: bytes
ETag: "cb25e8931048cd1:0"
Server: Microsoft-IIS/8.0
P3P: CP="ALL IND DSP COR ADM CONo CUR CUSo IVAo IVDo PSA PSD TAI TELo OUR SAMo CNT COM INT NAV ONL PHY PRE PUR UNI"
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
Date: Tue, 12 Jun 2012 15:09:06 GMT


DownloadManager Information: 0 : Remote file has not changed, using local cached file: C:\Users\<userName>\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Web Platform Installer\-1897360160.xml.temp
DownloadManager Information: 0 : Filtering by majorOS: 6, minorOS: 1, majorSP: 1, minorSP: 0, productType: 4, architecture: x64
DownloadManager Information: 0 : Loading product xml from: https://www.microsoft.com/web/webpi/4.0/webapplicationlist.xml
DownloadManager Information: 0 : https://www.microsoft.com/web/webpi/4.0/webapplicationlist.xml responded with 304
DownloadManager Information: 0 : Response headers:
HTTP/1.1 304 Not Modified
Cache-Control: max-age=900
Accept-Ranges: bytes
ETag: "5743f5d2148cd1:0"
Server: Microsoft-IIS/8.0
P3P: CP="ALL IND DSP COR ADM CONo CUR CUSo IVAo IVDo PSA PSD TAI TELo OUR SAMo CNT COM INT NAV ONL PHY PRE PUR UNI"
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
Date: Tue, 12 Jun 2012 15:09:06 GMT


DownloadManager Information: 0 : Remote file has not changed, using local cached file: C:\Users\<userName>\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Web Platform Installer\251486345.xml.temp
DownloadManager Warning: 0 : Could not resolve keyword ID ApplicationSpotlight
DownloadManager Warning: 0 : Could not resolve keyword ID ApplicationSpotlight
DownloadManager Warning: 0 : Could not resolve keyword ID ApplicationSpotlight
DownloadManager Warning: 0 : Could not resolve keyword ID ApplicationSpotlight
DownloadManager Warning: 0 : Could not resolve keyword ID ApplicationSpotlight
DownloadManager Warning: 0 : Could not resolve keyword ID ApplicationSpotlight
DownloadManager Warning: 0 : Could not resolve keyword ID ApplicationSpotlight
DownloadManager Warning: 0 : Could not resolve keyword ID ApplicationSpotlight
DownloadManager Warning: 0 : Could not resolve keyword ID ApplicationSpotlight
DownloadManager Warning: 0 : Could not resolve keyword ID ApplicationSpotlight
DownloadManager Warning: 0 : Could not resolve keyword ID ApplicationSpotlight
DownloadManager Warning: 0 : Could not resolve keyword ID ApplicationSpotlight
DownloadManager Warning: 0 : Could not resolve keyword ID ApplicationSpotlight
DownloadManager Warning: 0 : Could not resolve keyword ID ApplicationSpotlight
DownloadManager Information: 0 : Filtering by majorOS: 6, minorOS: 1, majorSP: 1, minorSP: 0, productType: 4, architecture: x64
DownloadManager Information: 0 : Loading product xml from: https://www.microsoft.com/web/webpi/4.0/mediaproductlist.xml
DownloadManager Information: 0 : https://www.microsoft.com/web/webpi/4.0/mediaproductlist.xml responded with 304
DownloadManager Information: 0 : Response headers:
HTTP/1.1 304 Not Modified
Cache-Control: max-age=900
Accept-Ranges: bytes
ETag: "5d94f4ad344cd1:0"
Server: Microsoft-IIS/8.0
P3P: CP="ALL IND DSP COR ADM CONo CUR CUSo IVAo IVDo PSA PSD TAI TELo OUR SAMo CNT COM INT NAV ONL PHY PRE PUR UNI"
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
Date: Tue, 12 Jun 2012 15:09:07 GMT


DownloadManager Information: 0 : Remote file has not changed, using local cached file: C:\Users\<userName>\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Web Platform Installer\598799360.xml.temp
DownloadManager Information: 0 : Filtering by majorOS: 6, minorOS: 1, majorSP: 1, minorSP: 0, productType: 4, architecture: x64
DownloadManager Information: 0 : Loading product xml from: https://www.microsoft.com/web/webpi/4.0/toolsproductlist.xml
DownloadManager Information: 0 : https://www.microsoft.com/web/webpi/4.0/toolsproductlist.xml responded with 304
DownloadManager Information: 0 : Response headers:
HTTP/1.1 304 Not Modified
Cache-Control: max-age=900
Accept-Ranges: bytes
ETag: "f752fed6ed47cd1:0"
Server: Microsoft-IIS/8.0
P3P: CP="ALL IND DSP COR ADM CONo CUR CUSo IVAo IVDo PSA PSD TAI TELo OUR SAMo CNT COM INT NAV ONL PHY PRE PUR UNI"
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
Date: Tue, 12 Jun 2012 15:09:07 GMT         

DownloadManager Information: 0 : Remote file has not changed, using local cached file: C:\Users\<userName>\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Web Platform Installer\1505006577.xml.temp
DownloadManager Information: 0 : Filtering by majorOS: 6, minorOS: 1, majorSP: 1, minorSP: 0, productType: 4, architecture: x64
DownloadManager Information: 0 : Getting ratings file from http://go.microsoft.com/?linkid=9752395
DownloadManager Information: 0 : http://go.microsoft.com/?linkid=9752395 responded with 302
DownloadManager Information: 0 : Response headers:
HTTP/1.1 302 Found
Cache-Control: private
Content-Length: 203
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Expires: Tue, 12 Jun 2012 15:08:08 GMT
Location: http://www.microsoft.com/web/handlers/WebPI.ashx?command=getatomfeedwithavgratingquery
Server: Microsoft-IIS/7.5
X-AspNet-Version: 2.0.50727
Set-Cookie: MC1=GUID=42969058f2d7c34ba4fcbc951f9b2694&HASH=5890&LV=20126&V=3; domain=microsoft.com; expires=Sun, 03-Oct-2010 07:00:00 GMT; path=/
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
Date: Tue, 12 Jun 2012 15:09:07 GMT


DownloadManager Information: 0 : Contextual entry products: mvc4vs2010
DownloadManager Information: 0 : Adding product ASP.NET MVC 4 Installer (Visual Studio 2010) (MVC4VS2010) to cart
DownloadManager Information: 0 : Contextual navigation to product 'MVC4VS2010'
DownloadManager Information: 0 : Ratings file loaded successfully
DownloadManager Information: 0 : Adding product 'MVC4VS2010'
DownloadManager Information: 0 : Setting current install to 1
DownloadManager Information: 0 : Starting install sequence
DownloadManager Information: 0 : Downloading file 'http://download.microsoft.com/download/A/A/4/AA42BC20-1656-4B28-B3EB-F2728124C5AA/AspNetMVC4Setup.exe' to: C:\Users\<userName>\AppData\Local\Temp\tmp430A.tmp
DownloadManager Information: 0 : Content-disposition header: attachment
DownloadManager Information: 0 : File 'C:\Users\<userName>\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Web Platform Installer\installers\MVC4VS2010\8EDB940F9A4EEC0C0F0324B5D647F17738C665CA\AspNetMVC4Setup.exe' already exists, deleting old copy of the file
DownloadManager Information: 0 : Moving downloaded file 'C:\Users\<userName>\AppData\Local\Temp\tmp430A.tmp' to: C:\Users\<userName>\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Web Platform Instal
```

Comment: wound up being a system environment issue and i had to have my help desk team reimage, I thought the question was obvious to see if anyone had a similar issue or could offer some insight.